# Use trackpad for annotation in Preview without clicking

Tags: macos, pdf, preview

Is there a way to annotate PDF's without clicking the trackpad? Something more like writing on paper.

I love that markdown lets us annotate stuff to PDF's using preview. But its slightly impractical - always having to press down.

Is there an app or a toggle which can let me go into writing mode so that I don't need to keep the trackpad clicked while "writing" so to say.

Answer (score 1):

If your MacBook has a Force Touch trackpad, you can use the Draw tool instead of the Sketch tool.

> Draw <sub><sub><sub>[image]</sub></sub></sub>
>
> Draw a shape using a single stroke. Press your finger more firmly on the trackpad to draw with a heavier, darker line.
>
> This tool appears only on computers with a Force Touch trackpad.

<sup>https://support.apple.com/kb/PH20218</sup>

Comment: I don't have a Force Touch trackpad. I'm using a 2014 Macbook Air :(